# How to write a binary matrix with fixed point elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to write a matrix 25 by 8 with each column represent a bit value and also want to make it a fixed point binary representation i.e. i want to write binary in decimal as

```
0000.1000 = .5 so in this expression the binary fixed point is at mid
So like wise a matrix
s=[0000.1000;
   0000.0100;
   ........
   .....
   0000.1100]
```

I want to keep this format for the whole matrix or something like that and also whos command will show me the class as binary. Thanks

Comment: what is your input and output format? show some example

Comment: Do you want to convert decimal numbers to this format, or what do you need as input?

Comment: Have you checked [matlab file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5396-conversion-of-fractions-from-binary-to-decimal-and-vice-versa) (or [this file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13899-floating-number-conversion-to-binary-and-vice-versa))? Further, is it the visual representation in the command window that matters or is it some calculation you want to want to perform?

Comment: Getting the bits is easy. I have no clue how to create an array of class binary in Matlab.